# Javascript in php not giving proper result

Tags: php, javascript

```
$a = '<script language="javascript"> var a="1"; document.write(a);</script>';
echo "A is: ".$a."<br>";
if($a == 1)
{
echo "Its 1";
}
else
{
echo "Its not 1";
}
```

I get the following output -
 
    A is: 1
    Its not 1

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: javascript runs in the browser, php on your server...

Comment: Looks like he's using PHP to echo out HTML and JS.

Comment: So there is no way to get this thing work properly ?

Comment: Mixing JS, HTML and PHP is fine presuming you understand that one set of technologies run in the browser (HTML and JS, client side) and the other on the server (PHP, server side).

Answer (score 1):

`$a` is not equal to `1`. You've set it equal to `<script language="javascript"> var a="1"; document.write(a);</script><br>`, so failing the check would be expected.

Comment: Right, I got that when I did var_dump, but am working on a bigger project where I need to do comparison this way. Is there any other way?

Comment: Generally speaking, comparison that way works fine when dealing with numbers. Here, `$a` is a string and not going to equal `1`. If you're looking to test whether a string is not empty (neither blank nor null), try `empty()`.